# Ionic 4 Router does not have navigate and navigateByUrl

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, router, angular-routing, ionic4

I am implementing router in Ionic 4, basically just want to navigate from one to another page.

I implemented the code as below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Route } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-secure2fa',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  introFlag; any = false;
  userName: String;
  loading: any;

  constructor(private route: Route)
  {

  }

  goRegister() {
    this.route.navigateByUrl('/secure-registration');
  }
}
```

The secure-registration page is create using Ionic CLI command so it automatically get added to app-routing.module as below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'location', loadChildren: './location/location.module#LocationPageModule' },
  { path: 'secure-registration', loadChildren: './secure-registration/secure-registration.module#SecureRegistrationPageModule' },
  { path: 'success-registration', loadChildren: './success-registration/success-registration.module#SuccessRegistrationPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The problem I got here is that navigateByUrl or even navigate is not found. Error as below:

> Property 'navigateByUrl' does not exist on type 'Route'.

Anyone know if I have missed something here. I am using Ionic 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing **Route**, You should be importing **Router**.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

And inject the same into your class.

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking that Router or Route is just the name convention that I declare. Thanks for that. Sorry for silly mistake since I am new to Ionic and Typescript/Angular.